Why does Trying to make an ajax call attached to a class on load fail with multiple elements?
The attachment shows in console, but the ajax call is never made.
This is the HTML I am using to attach the ajax call:
<tr>
    <td>Sitename1</td>
    <td class="ajax-delsite" data-site="sitename1" id="sitename1">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sitename2</td>' . "\n";
    <td class="ajax-delsite" data-site="sitename2" id="sitename2">
    </td>
</tr>

And this is the jquery that is failing:
$(".ajax-delsite").on('load', function(e){
    var site = $(this).data("site");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/remove-site.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { site: site },
        success: function(feedback){ 
            $("#ajaxResult").html(feedback);
        }
    });
});

What am I doing wrong?
UPDATE: Thanks in large part to DankDizaster's solution, I ended up fixing it with this:
$(".ajax-delsite").each(function(e){
    var site = $(this).data("site");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/remove-site.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { site: site },
        success: function(feedback){ 
            $('#'+site).html(feedback);
        }
    });
});


Do you want to make a ajax call when load page or click button?

What makes you think a td has a load event? What would load even mean for a td in HTML?

load is not supported by the td element, you can read more about supported elements here.
In your case you could use the JQuery's document ready


$(document).ready(function () {
    const site = $(".ajax-delsite").data("site");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/remove-site.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { site: site },
        success: function (feedback) {
            $("#ajaxResult").html(feedback);
        }
    });
});




Would that get all instances of .ajax-delsite class on page? There are multiple, each its own call.

No it would not, you would need to add all the calls one after the other inside the ready function.
